# How to draw a OpenCV circle with two circumference point

Tags: python, opencv

Does anyone know how I'd go about drawing an OpenCV circle with two circumference points?
I am using some ArUco tags to create a marker. The map looks like the one attached
[image: My map]

All help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by two circumference points? I think there are an infinite number of circles that satisfy that condition.

Comment: Just two points on a circumference a diameter (of the circle) apart.

Comment: Using @diylmma's answer works, just average the coordinates of the two points to get the center and get the radius by finding the distance from the center to one of the circumference points.

Comment: What's the point of the answer? Getting the points from markers? Drawing the circumference given the points? For the latter case: @diylimma's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The opencv [circle()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf10604b069374903dbd0f0488cb43670) function takes a radius and center point as input.  Your circumference points can give you this information.  The center is the midpoint of your two points, and the radius is half the distance between them.